# R: poly_center out of polygon bounds

Tags: r, polygon, r-sp

I´m using R to calculate the center of mass of the polygon defined by the figure read in this [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-NeuuVjTy4IQmRINVZHb1ZWNkE/view?usp=sharing), using poly_center (pracma package).

Oddly enough, the result I´m getting is out of the polygon bounds, being the center point lower than both, the minimum values of x (lon) and y (lat) axis/coordinates (see code below). Could anyone hint me on what am I doing wrong or what is going on here?

```
    # loading needed packages
    require(pracma)
    require(sp)
    t <- read.csv(file="testcm.txt",head=FALSE,row.names=NULL)[-1,] # readind file
    attach(t)
    lon <- V1
    lat <- V2
    cm <- poly_center(lon,lat) # center of mass
    cm
    [1] -49.92585 -16.52163
    min(lon)
    [1] -49.05978
    min(lat)
    [1] -16.45963
    plot(coordinates(t), type="n", xlab="longitude", ylab="latitude", xlim=c(-65,-40) , ylim=c(-35,-10)) # drawing base contours
    polygon(lon, lat, border = "red") # drawing polygon
    points(cm[1],cm[2], pch=22, col="blue") # drawing center of mass
```

Comment: Since we don't have your CSV file, posting `read.csv()` doesn't help much. Maybe you could post `dput(t)`? Also, I'd strongly recommend *never* using `attac()`.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Gregor. Actually I uploaded the file [here] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-NeuuVjTy4IQmRINVZHb1ZWNkE/view?pli=1) . It is also in the question above.

Cheers and thanks again!

Comment: `points(t(colMeans(coordinates(t))), col="red")` gives an approximate center

Comment: This is true @nongkrong. It works in this case as well as for "regular" shapes. Unfortunately the means wouldn´t give me the desired result in "L" shapes for instance...:(

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `poly_center`, you may need to bind the first row of your polygon coordinates to the end as well.  It doesn't look like the code accounts for wrapping the last point back to the first.

Try

```
tmp <- rbind(coordinates(t), coordinates(t)[1,])
points(t(poly_center(tmp[,1], tmp[,2])), col="green", pch=16)
```

Comment: That solved it @nongkrong! I had a loop among many polygons and this happened to be the only one with this issue! Thanks a lot!

Cheers!

Comment: @HelioCamargo glad to hear it :)